# firebase unauthorized access flutter app login

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to configure a purchased code canyon flutter app for a client and I faced this error:

when I register a user, they get added to users in firebase.

I try to log in with the same users that exist on firebase it returns me `unauthorized access`

I do verify users through the link that be sent to the registered email.

the same thing happens either with email or google sign-in.

at the same time, this console error got printed:

```
D/FirebaseAuth( 3993): Notifying id token listeners about a sign-out event.
D/FirebaseAuth( 3993): Notifying auth state listeners about a sign-out event.
W/System  ( 3993): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/System  ( 3993): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/FirebaseAuth( 3993): Notifying id token listeners about user ( 0pwQv6Jo6ia59AE5NZ26JEboRle2 ).
D/FirebaseAuth( 3993): Notifying auth state listeners about user ( 0pwQv6Jo6ia59AE5NZ26JEboRle2 ).
```

I am using the latest `firebase_auth` and `firebase_core`

Does any one faced this error before?

Comment: The information is not enough, what returns you unauthorized access, the backend call, or firebase

Comment: Oh let me check something actually and get back to you!

Comment: It is coming from firebase, the auth functionality they are using firebase.